# Creating JOptionPane and their object with fixed width and height

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

[image]

I am trying create a `JOptionPane` just like this. I try many Layout Manager but (`GridBagLayout`, `GridLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout`) but i am not succeed yet.

For example if i use `GridBagLayout`, `ipadx` really helpfull but `JTextFields` width depends in their text length.

If i use `GridLayout`, every objects width belongs to columns width.

If i use `AbsoluteLayout`, `JOptionPane` not expand itself to configured `JPanel` bounds which carry objects.

I need fixed object widths, heights and `JOptionPane` should expand itself when we create it with `JPanel` which carry items.

Which Layout Manager optimum for this mission? I will focus on it if you suggest.

**--EDIT--**

GridLayout example;

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(8, 2) );

JLabel inforForNameLabel = new JLabel();
inforForNameLabel.setText("Long Label Name....................................");

final JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField();
userNameTextField.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
userNameTextField.setEditable(false);

JLabel inforForNameSurname = new JLabel();
inforForNameSurname.setText("Long Label Name..................................");

final JTextField NameSurnameTextField = new JTextField();
NameSurnameTextField.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa");

JLabel inforForStatsCombobox = new JLabel();
inforForStatsCombobox.setText("Long Label Name.................................");

JComboBox statComboBox = new JComboBox();
DefaultComboBoxModel dt = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
statComboBox.setModel(dt);
dt.addElement("USER.....");
dt.addElement("ADMIN");
statComboBox.setSelectedItem("USER.....");

JLabel inforForAuthCombobox = new JLabel();
inforForAuthCombobox.setText("Long Label Name.................................");

String[] authComboBoxObjects = { "READ", "READ/WRITE"};
final JComboBox authComboBox = new JComboBox(authComboBoxObjects);
authComboBox.setSelectedItem("READ/WRITE");

panel.add(inforForNameLabel);
panel.add(userNameTextField);
panel.add(inforForNameSurname);
panel.add(NameSurnameTextField);
panel.add(inforForStatsCombobox);
panel.add(statComboBox);
panel.add(inforForAuthCombobox);
panel.add(authComboBox);

String[] buttons = { "EXIT", "OK" };
int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel,"User Config", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[1]);

if(rc == 0 || rc == -1){
     System.out.println(userNameTextField.getText());
}
else{
     System.out.println("Cancel...");
}
```

Comment: You know....in my opinion, for what it takes to force a JOptionPane to Look and react exactly as you want, it's better and easier just to use a JDialog. I mean after all, it can be Modal as well.

Comment: Actually right i will use `JDialog` but just i need to know how can i make same thing via `JOptionPane`

Comment: Let's have a look at what you have tried already.

Comment: I recommend BoxLayout

Comment: I recommend using a `BoxLayout` (Y_AXIS) that contains rows of `JPanel` each set to `FlowLayout`. Works very well for adaptable grid layouts, if `GridLayout` / `GridBagLayout` aren't working for you.

Comment: I add GridLayout example. I will investigate BoxLayout. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the routed comments to @ControlAltDel and @Gorbles

Below codes build OptionPane which desired format at the Question;

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JLabel inforForNameLabel = new JLabel();
    inforForNameLabel.setText("Long Label Name.............................");
    inforForNameLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel inforForNameLabel2 = new JLabel();
    inforForNameLabel2.setText("Long Label Name............................");
    inforForNameLabel2.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    final JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField();
    userNameTextField.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    userNameTextField.setEditable(false);
    userNameTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(345, 30));
    userNameTextField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(345, 30));
    userNameTextField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel inforForNameSurname = new JLabel();
    inforForNameSurname.setText("Long Label Nameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    inforForNameSurname.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    final JTextField NameSurnameTextField = new JTextField();
    NameSurnameTextField.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa");
    NameSurnameTextField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(345, 30));
    NameSurnameTextField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(345, 30));
    NameSurnameTextField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel inforForStatsCombobox = new JLabel();
    inforForStatsCombobox.setText("Long Label Name....................");
    inforForStatsCombobox.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JComboBox statComboBox = new JComboBox();
    DefaultComboBoxModel dt = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    statComboBox.setModel(dt);
    dt.addElement("USER.....");
    dt.addElement("ADMIN");
    statComboBox.setSelectedItem("USER.....");
    statComboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    statComboBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    statComboBox.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel inforForAuthCombobox = new JLabel();
    inforForAuthCombobox.setText("Long Label Name................................");
    inforForAuthCombobox.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    String[] authComboBoxObjects = { "READ", "READ/WRITE"};
    final JComboBox authComboBox = new JComboBox(authComboBoxObjects);
    authComboBox.setSelectedItem("READ/WRITE");
    authComboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    authComboBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    authComboBox.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);


    panel.add(inforForNameLabel);
    panel.add(inforForNameLabel2);
    panel.add(userNameTextField);
    panel.add(inforForNameSurname);
    panel.add(NameSurnameTextField);
    panel.add(inforForStatsCombobox);
    panel.add(statComboBox);
    panel.add(inforForAuthCombobox);
    panel.add(authComboBox);

    String[] buttons = { "EXIT", "OK" };
    int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel,"User Config", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[1]);

    if(rc == 0 || rc == -1){
        System.out.println("Cancel...");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(userNameTextField.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed a JDialog gives you total control.

> i need to know how can i make same thing via JOptionPane

The UIManager seems to control the minimum size. Before displaying the option pane you can override by using:

```
Dimension size = UIManager.getDimension("OptionPane.minimumSize");
size.width = 100;
UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", size);
```

You can check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for a list of other properties controlled by the UIManager. Be aware that it is not guaranteed that all LAF's will manage the same properties.

Comment: Code return exception in `size.width = 100;` Also if we change OptionPane size all objects extend to the last size of OptionPane if we use GridLayout. I will use BoxLayout for this operation as @ControlAltDel and @Gorbles said.

Comment: @BlackWhite, works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7.